# Help with identifying the brand of a vintage bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

I've been trying to find out about the provenance of a vintage bike.

It is fitted with:

- a USA Sturmey Archer 4 speed FW.63
- Wagner Werdermann front hub
- The brakes are Weinmann.
- Cranks are Williams.

The wheel chain is either a triangle or a pine tree.

On the frame, there is a double ram horns

Wheels are 27x 1 1/4 or 32-630

And on the fork, there is a light bracket.

The plaque has been removed.
No markings anywhere visible.

It seems to be hand painted.

It looks better than in the pics.

Thank you for your help!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd guess its a 60s or 70s bike based on the cottered crank.  The 4 speed hub probably dates it best of all, assuming that was original.  The weinmann caliper brakes are about early 1980s based on other bikes I've seen with them.  Sorry - no idea on maker or brand.

Comment: To my shame, I had to look the word "provenance" up to learn it is "origin". Otherwise I thought it was a brand name and thus had to be written from a capital letter…

Answer (score 6):

I might have found its provenance from the net.
Pinterest lugs

Amstrong.

Your points of views?
Thanks

[image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Those two chainrings are so close in size that it hardly seems worth having two!

Comment: @DavidRicherby look up half step gearing for explanation

Comment: @ojs Thanks for making sure I learnt something new today. :-)

Comment: Easier to shift up to the big ring as well.

Comment: @ConnoisseurEquator  Great finding - thank you for coming back and providing closure too.  Do mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkbox on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

The lugs are Oscar Egg Super Champion, see http://www.classiclightweights.co.uk/components/oscaregg.html, which doesn't narrow down the maker in any way but does suggest a frame of at least reasonable quality.

Also the front hub says "Made in Jermany" not "Werdermann". Possibly pre-war as I'd expect "West Germany" after, but given the mis-spelling I'd put a low confidence on this. Also this article https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fosthessen-news.de%2Fn11570883%2Fvon-der-jagdwaffe-zum-ventil-fahrzeugteile-von-wagner-stecken-in-jedem-auto.html suggests it would have been "Luck & Wagner" pre-war.

Comment: Great finding!   To clarify, these lugs were available as parts, and could have been used by a number of different framebuilders.